# Post values encoding issue. £ turning into Â£

Tags: php, post, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to solve an issue with my website.  If I submit a form containing the `£` symbol **to the same page**, it comes back as `Â£` even before it hits my database.

I have tried the following in my  tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

**and**

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

I've tried all of these at the start of every page:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mb_internal_encoding('utf-8');
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

I also have the `SET NAMES` in my database connection string:

```
new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=########", "##########", "######", array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
```

At first I thought it was my database, because the values were being stored in there with these values - however I have realised if I submit my form and it has validation errors, I pick up the submitted value via `$_POST[]` and it returns the value in the textbox with the strange characters.

It works perfectly fine on my local WAMP server, but when I run my website in my live environment - this is when I hit the problem with the encoding.

Does anyone have any other suggestions that I can try to fix it?

Comment: Are your PHP files *saved* as UTF-8?

Comment: I can see that it's transfered as `&acirc;�&not;`. Do you use `htmlentities` to fix XSS? Are you making sure to use `UTF-8` as param #3? I don't know your PHP version, but the manual specifies: *Like htmlspecialchars(), htmlentities() takes an optional third argument encoding which defines encoding used in conversion. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards.*

Comment: You sir, have made my day!  Yes, I hadn't included the encoding on HTMLENTITIES().  Now that I've added that in it displays fine... I will be putting that in a function and using it site wide now.  Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll accept! Thank you soooooo much!  My WAMP server was using a more up to date version of PHP, hense why it was working on my local and not on my hosting.

Comment: Glad I could help. It's incredibly stupid that PHP has any static encoding in `htmlentities` by default, and doesn't use the `default_charset` by default instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your live server uses a PHP version less than 5.4.0, and hence when you use [`htmlentities`](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) it defaults to ISO-8859-1, as the [manual](http://www.php.net/htmlentities) specifies:

> Like htmlspecialchars(), htmlentities() takes an optional third argument encoding which defines encoding used in conversion. If omitted, the default value for this argument is ISO-8859-1 in versions of PHP prior to 5.4.0, and UTF-8 from PHP 5.4.0 onwards.

You can fix this by using `UTF-8` as the third parameter, or simply make your own function that defaults to it:

```
if (!function_exists('htmlentities_utf8')) {
    function htmlentities_utf8($string, $flags = null, $encoding = 'UTF-8', $double_encode = true) {
        if ($flags === null) {
            $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401;
        }

        return htmlentities($string, $flags, $encoding, $double_encode);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you ever plan on using another encoding, you can make it grab the `default_charset` value:

```
if (!function_exists('htmlentities_dc')) {
    function htmlentities_dc($string, $flags = null, $encoding = null, $double_encode = true) {
        if ($flags === null) {
            $flags = ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401;
        }

        if ($encoding === null) {
            $encoding = ini_get('default_charset');
        }

        return htmlentities($string, $flags, $encoding, $double_encode);
    }
}
```

Comment: Loving the second function there, I'll be using that!  Thank you!

Comment: @Coulton I've made a slight change (parameters can't have bitwise in them, so I've put it down the function instead).